# set_richText is not a function

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

Trying to set the RichText property of MultiLineText to true using JavaScript Client Object Model. Getting error:

> set_richText is not a function

Sample Code:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("LibTest");
var listFields = list.get_fields();
clientContext.load(listFields);
var multilineField = listFields.getByInternalNameOrTitle("FeedbackURL");
clientContext.load(multilineField);
multilineField.set_richText(true);
multilineField.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {console.log('success');}, function() {console.log('failure');});
```

How is [richText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj247180.aspx) property supposed to be used.

Able to set title of the field properly using `multilineField.set_title('UpdatedTitle');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The field needs to be casted to `SP.FieldMultiLineText`. Working code:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("LibTest");
var listFields = list.get_fields();
clientContext.load(listFields);
var field = listFields.getByInternalNameOrTitle("FeedbackURL");
var multilineField = clientContext.castTo(field, SP.FieldMultiLineText);
clientContext.load(field);
multilineField.set_richText(true);
multilineField.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {console.log('success');}, function() {console.log('failure');});
```